# How do I fix this leaking dishwasher drain pipe?

Tags: plumbing, leak, dishwasher, hose

There is a leaking hose connection to the pump in my dishwasher. I have tried silicone and a hose clamp but no no avail.

What can I do to fix this?
Picture before the silicone, the corrosion is from the leaking wastewater.
[image]

Comment: A picture of the problematic hose would really help narrow down the possible solutions.

Comment: best would be to clean it all up first. adding/replacing a hose clamp only helps if it is the clamped joint leaking, and that might not be clear in current state. If it is leaking at the joint between plastic elbow and rubber boot, adding a hose clamp or tightening the one you have won't help. Once you can see where it is leaking, you should be able to tell if it is the clamped joint or the hose assembly. If the latter, just buy a new one. (online or someplace that sells appliance parts)

Answer (score 3):

I would start by cleaning up the corrosion and debris. If possible remove the hose/boot and clean any debris from the inside sealing surface. Inspect the hose for any cracks or holes. Looking at the photo the bottom clamp appears to be installed correctly. The upper hose appears to be installed too low. The clamp is squeezing the hose but not the pipe. The clamp should be against the shoulder/flange of the hose.

Comment: Sure does look too low.  Cleaning it up and running the dishwasher he should see if that is indeed where the water is leaking out.